# Npm error occuring when trying to run npm install -g npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

Receiving the foillowing error, when I try to search C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules@npmcli via run app it tell mes that it cannot find the file

[error when using run command to find path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D456k.png)

[Picture of error code in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDxi.png)
C:\GreaterWMS\templates>npm install -g npm
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules@npmcli
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules@npmcli
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules@npmcli' -> 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules@npmcli'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules@npmcli' -> 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules@npmcli'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules@npmcli' -> 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules@npmcli'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules\@npmcli',
npm ERR!     dest: 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\@npmcli'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules\@npmcli',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\@npmcli',
npm ERR!   parent: 'npm'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-15T14_28_23_790Z-debug.log

I have no idea how to fix this error, I have tried creating a temporary cache I have wiped my entire computer and reset and restarted the entire process from scratch but I keep receiving this same error.

1. I have turned off my firewall
   2.I have turned off all anti virus software
   3.I have tried deleting the Roaming data npm folder and tried to reinstall npm, but everything that I try to do nothing will fix this error.
2. thought maybe because my user for my microsoft is 2 names (First and Last, I then turn my pc into a local machine so it the user would only be "harka"

Answer (score 1):

And have you installed npm previously, can you run for example `npm -v` ? if not, that means u don't have npm installed at all and you trying to use it to install npm (if I am not mistaken)
Then assuming you are using windows, the best way to install npm to windows is to download node.js from [their official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), which installs npm as well.

Comment: Hey Roman, can confirm I do have npm installed verion 6.14.15. however when I look at my global dependencies the command  'npm list -g -depth=0' I receive the following error for npm package " error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\harka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\package.json" as well if that provides any insight

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing this because `npm` just asked me to upgrade itself and then I got the same error and Google brought me here.

Instead of doing that, I installed the Windows 64 MSI from [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and it upgraded node and npm with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you have mismatched versions of the Angular CLI, Node.js, and NPM.  Run the following at the command line and see if the versions you have installed are compatible with the project requirements in the package.json file:

```
> ng version
```

It should produce something like this:

[image]

If you notice any lines that say `<error>`, you need to address those.  Sometimes a corrupted `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package will cause multiple errors and it may need to be installed manually with the following command (the version 13 can be changed to your project requirements):

```
> npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@13 --force
```